# Failed to resolve import "React" in npm package and webpack 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, vite

I am developing a npm package and use there webpack 5.
This is my config

```
const path = require('path') // resolve path
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'], // we can import without typing '.js or .jsx'
    },
    entry: {
        index: path.join(__dirname, 'src/index.jsx'),
    },

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'index.js', // for production use [contenthash], for developement use [hash]
        library: {
            type: 'module',
        },
        environment: { module: true },
    },
    experiments: {
        outputModule: true,
    },
    devtool: 'eval',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(css|scss|sass)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader', // creates style nodes from JS strings
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader', // translates CSS into CommonJS
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader', // compiles Sass to CSS
                    },
                ],
            },

            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /nodeModules/,

                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
                exclude:
                    /images/ /* dont want svg images from image folder to be included */,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            outputPath: 'fonts/',
                            name: '[name][hash].[ext]',
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    externals: {
        react: 'React',
        'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
    },

    plugins: [],
}
```

When I want to import components from this library I get this error:

```
Failed to resolve import "React" from "..my-package/dist/index.js". Does the file exist?
```

I think this has something to do with externals react and react-dom. But when I remove the externals from webpack config I get the error that react should be only installed once when using react hooks.
In my main application I am using vite for bundeling  but I tried it also with create-react-app and have the same problem.

My Library Component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
    return <div>{counter}</div>
}

export default App
```

This is how I am using it with npm-link:

```
import React from "react";
import Test from "my-package";
const App = () => {
  return <Test />;
};

export default App;
```

Here is the repo with the code https://github.com/guitar9/webpack-bug

Comment: Why are you trying to import `React` from your package?

Comment: Because I am using it and return a react component

Comment: instead of exporting React from your package, just export your component.
Try this article https://dev.to/jimjunior/how-to-create-an-npm-library-from-react-components-2m2.

Comment: @BharatDBhadresha I tried this articel but there I am getting other errors. I update the question and added the code for my library and how I am using it

Comment: Please share your sample code in a codesanbox or similar service?

Comment: @BharatDBhadresha I will create a repo to demonstrate this error

Comment: @BharatDBhadresha here is the repo https://github.com/guitar9/webpack-bug

Comment: I also added the code with rollup.js to the branch rollup. There I am getting this error: nnot set properties of undefined (setting 'runtime')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240944/discussion-between-bharat-d-bhadresha-and-otto).